# Is Anna Maria a child?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

It is my understanding that when Otto Octavious' mind was in Peter Parker's body he fell in love with Anna Maria.  This led me to wonder approximately how old Anna Maria is supposed to be. I didn't read the Superior Spider-man series, but every picture I've seen of her makes her appear to be a young child, definitely no older than high school age.

So is Anna Maria supposed to be a child or does her young appearance have a different explanation (e.g. I'm misreading the art, she was hit with an age-regression ray, etc.)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Anna Maria Marconi is a "[little person](http://www.lpaonline.org/faq-)" (as she, herself describes).

> The words you're looking for are "Little Person." And, yes, I am.

Her age is never specified, but it was my impression that she is perhaps slightly younger than Peter, but still of college age.

[image: scan]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a lack of data, or a surprising degree of Political Correctness / tact -- the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Anna_Maria_Marconi_%28Earth-616%29) only mentions her size under "Unusual Features: Short Stature"

Comment: I am not a little person, so my understanding may be flawed, but according to the link in the answer, "Short Stature" is an acceptable term describing this condition rather than just meaning she's short in general.

Comment: @Yamikuronue: It seems to depend on where you live. My mother is a "little person," and she'd punch you in the stomach if you called her that. Call her a midget, on the other hand, and she's quite happy. The American "little people" couple I met once told me they considered midget to be the second-worst thing they could be called, besides dwarf. The Kiwi "little people" I met at university all told me they preferred "dwarf." So good luck to *Marvel* in finding a term that doesn't piss off somebody.